# Reference a cell within a cell reference?

Tags: office365

Ok, so I'm trying to set up a kind of debug sheet for a project I'm working on.

On the sheet I have a range of values from cells b1 the b20 and in c1 thru c20 I have a cost. These cost are dependant upon the cell above.

In the debug section, I want to be able to input a value, say 18, and have it return in the next cell the cost from C18

If I put in a 16, it'll return c16.

This is of course in the cell right next to where I input my test number.

How would I do this?

Comment: The question is not very clear, but `=Index(C:C, A1)` returns the value from cell `C18` if cell `A1` contains the number `18`

Comment: That might be exactly what I'm needing. Let me check it real quick.

Comment: Yep, that does it. Wanna put that in a normal answer? I'll up vote it for you as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index`, `Offset`, and `Indirect` are some of the main functions to reference a cell.

[Lookup and reference functions (reference)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lookup-and-reference-functions-reference-8aa21a3a-b56a-4055-8257-3ec89df2b23e)